# How can I create a trigger that adds a record to a different table when a record is changed on my source table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

What I want to do seems relatively simple. I have 2 tables, [ideas] and [my_projects]. What I am looking for is a trigger that will add the record from ideas to my_projects  when the status of the idea status is changed to "closed". 
Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerNEWPROJECT ON IDEAS
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
DECLARE 
@ID varchar(255), @NEW_STATUS varchar(255), @NEW_NAME varchar(255), @OLD_STATUS varchar(255);
SET @ID = IDEAS.ID;
SET @NEW_STATUS = 'NEW';
set @NEW_NAME = new.NAME
set @OLD_STATUS = (SELECT STATUS FROM IDEAS WHERE ID = @ID)
BEGIN
if @OLD_STATUS = 'closed'
    INSERT INTO MY_PROJECTS (IDEA_ID, STATUS) VALUES(@ID, @NEW_NAME, @NEW_NAME);
END;
```

When an Idea status is updated to "Closed", I would like it to create a project with the same name as the Idea that was just closed, but with a Status of "New" in the My_Projects table. 
This seems like it should be easy, but it is not working and it's pretty clear to me I don't know what I'm doing. 
Here is my trigger code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerNEWPROJECT ON IDEAS
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
DECLARE 
@ID varchar(255), @NEW_STATUS varchar(255), @NEW_NAME varchar(255), @OLD_STATUS varchar(255);
SET @ID = IDEAS.ID;
SET @NEW_STATUS = 'NEW';
set @NEW_NAME = new.NAME
set @OLD_STATUS = (SELECT STATUS FROM IDEAS WHERE ID = @ID)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO MY_PROJECTS (IDEA_ID, STATUS) VALUES(@ID, @NEW_NAME, @NEW_NAME);
END;
```

I would like the ID field in the Projects table to just auto_increment, and I believe I've set it up to do so. Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You need to look at the inserted and deleted virtual tables. Your trigger also has a MAJOR problem. It is assuming that only a single row will be updated. Triggers fire once per operation, not once per row and you need to handle it. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Not really sure why you are using an insert trigger here when part of the rule states that the status is being changed to 'closed'. It can't possibly be changing on an insert because it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: `(IDEA_ID, STATUS) VALUES (@ID, @NEW_NAME, @NEW_NAME)`: two columns, three values, and the `Status` will always be `'closed'`?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has a really convenient table `inserted` that exists during the transaction time of `insert/update` triggers.  The records in the `inserted` table will be the new records you are inserting or updating in `IDEAS`.

You can use it like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerNEWPROJECT ON IDEAS
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MY_PROJECTS (IDEA_ID, STATUS, NAME) 
    SELECT new.ID, 'New', new.Name
    FROM inserted new
    LEFT JOIN deleted old on new.ID = old.id
    WHERE old.status <> 'closed'
    AND new.status = 'closed'
END
```

Your current trigger is a little confusing, but that should be close to what you are looking for.  Adjust the column names as needed (for example, is project name = `name`?)

Comment: Need to add the check for the status being 'closed'.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks Sean, added

Comment: Why are you joining to IDEAS? If you want the changed values you join to deleted.

Comment: @SeanLange Does `deleted` exist for an insert?  Although I agree with your comment on the question that it seems like this is update only, and my trigger is written with that in mind anyway.

Comment: No. The deleted virtual table would not exist for an insert. There is no concept of a "previous" value for an insert. So joining to IDEAS to look for it would be pointless, it doesn't exist.

Comment: @SeanLange Exactly.. so to cover both insert and update isn't this the way to do that?

Comment: NO. You do a left join to deleted. Checking the table is rather silly.

Comment: @SeanLange Sorry for the bad wording... What I meant is, if this fires for an insert, and I have `LEFT JOIN deleted`, it won't throw a "`deleted` table does not exist" style error?

Comment: Nvm, just tried it and `deleted` exists it's just empty in that case.  Thanks for the advice